# About compile with .so in Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, .a

I have developed a shared library B.so, which depends on A.so.
When I write a program test.exe using B.so, but there is a compile error, it said that some symbols(the symbols are in A.so) not found. 
My build line:

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -fPIC -I./ -L./ -lB
```

Do we have a method that, how to build test.exe successfully,but not link A.so.

Comment: Have you tried linking with `A` as well?

Comment: yes, if I add the A.so, it will be OK. I want to build a SDK b.so, however I don't want building test.exe needs A.so

Comment: So you want the symbols (variables/functions/etc.) that are in your A library to just magically appear in anything linked with library B? That's not likely with most compilers. You could potentially include A in B in its entirety to get around that, though...

Comment: @twalberg Some time ago GNU `ld` had a different behavior in this kind of situation, it did link to `A.so` automatically. But it does not do it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to build test.exe successfully,but not link A.so.

There are at least two method:

1. export a proper `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/A
   gcc ... -lB
   ```
2. using `ld` option `-rpath` (discovered by the asker @iceKing himself)

   ```
   gcc -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/A ...
   ```

In both case, `ld` will automatically search for libraries depended by these libraries list explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However when build B.so, I use the link "-lrt -lcurl", but when build test.exe, they are not needed? why?

Comment: @iceKing Did you really use function from `libcurl.so` in your `B.so`?

Comment: Yes, maybe it choose the static library.

Comment: I have another method, but I don't know why. I copy the A.so to build folder, and add the flags "-Wl,-rpath=." then it will compile successfully.

Comment: @iceKing If you want to know, check out the explanation of `-rpath` option in `ld` man page.

Comment: @iceKing No, not at all, this is a very well question.